# lastPathComponent doesn't match deletingLastPathComponent

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a requirement to add   thumb_ to the the filename of a url

`let url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx-xx.xxxx.com/o/images%2Fjondoe%2F-ASDFASDFSDFAS.png?alt=media&token=xxxxx"`
   to convert this into

`let url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx-xx.xxxx.com/o/images%2Fjondoe%2Fthumb_-ASDFASDFSDFAS.png?alt=media&token=xxxxx"`

I got this working using

```
let webURL  = NSURL(string: url)

var pathArray : [String] = webURL!.pathComponents!

let thumbFile =  pathArray[pathArray.count - 3] + "/" + pathArray[pathArray.count - 2]+"/thumb_\(webURL!.lastPathComponent!)"
print( webURL!.deletingLastPathComponent)
let thumbURL = webURL!.deletingLastPathComponent?.appendingPathComponent(thumbFile)

print(thumbURL!)
```

What I see is the lastPathComponent gives just filename 
vs deletingLastPathComponent removes images%2Fjondoe%2Fthumb_-ASDFASDFSDFAS.png , I'm thinking there should be some more easy /break proof way of doing this, there are suggestions to use cloud functions 
etc looking forward to hear from you all

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs because the last two path separators are percent escaped (`%2F`) which confuses `deletingLastPathComponent()`

I recommend to call `removingPercentEncoding` before creating the URL to replace `%2F` with `/`

```
let urlString = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx-xx.xxxx.com/o/images%2Fjondoe%2F-ASDFASDFSDFAS.png?alt=media&token=xxxxx"
let clearedURLString = urlString.removingPercentEncoding!
let url = URL(string: clearedURLString)!
let thumbLastPathComponent = "thumb_" + url.lastPathComponent
let newURL = url.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent(thumbLastPathComponent)

print(newURL)
```

Normally the best solution would be to use `URLComponents`. But the percent escaped forward slash (`%2F`) is not recognized as a valid path separator.

The code is Swift 3, it's highly recommended to update, Swift 4 is raring to go.